# IF statement with 2 conditions and rounding numbers

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried using logical operators in if statements when combining 2 conditions in one IF statement.

I still fail to understand the difference between || and &&, could some one help please?

In this example when I calculate the body mass index value that has been inputted, it doesn't give me the right description, for the 2nd and 3rd IF statement. Also, how do I round BMI result into the nearest 10?

```
namespace draft {
public partial class Form1: Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        double weight = Convert.ToDouble(tbweight.Text);
        double height = Convert.ToDouble(tbheight.Text);
        double BMI = weight / Math.Pow(height, 2);
        lbresult.Text = "BMI Result: " + BMI;

        if (BMI < 18.5) {
            lbdescription.Text = "BMI Description: Your weight is extremely low";
            return;
        }
        if (BMI <= 18.5 && BMI < 25.0) {
            lbdescription.Text = "BMI Description: Your weight is in line with average";
        }
        if (BMI <= 25.0 && BMI < 30.0) {
            lbdescription.Text = "BMI Description: Your weight is over";
        }
        if (BMI >= 30.0) {
            lbdescription.Text = "BMI Description: Your weight is excess";
        }

    }
}
```

}

[after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StEh8.png)

Comment: This looks like just a typo.  You're using `<=` when you meant to use `>=`.  For example, `BMI <= 18.5 && BMI < 25.0` should be `BMI >= 18.5 && BMI < 25.0`.  (After all, any value that's less than 18.5 *will always be* less than 25.0)  The same typo is on the condition after that one as well.

Comment: If you use ||, *either* condition can be true and the if-statement will be entered. If you use &&, *both* conditions must be true for the if-statement to be entered. Most conditions can be read out loud as perfectly valid english, using "and" for && and "or" for ||, and it should make sense: "If BMI is less than or equal to 18.5 and BMI is less than 25.0, then..." (as David points out above, it's clear that your "less than" should be "greater than")

Comment: oh ok, my bad, I think this was the problem with it. Both logical operators did not work well. Thank you david! Now I just need to know how to round the result of BMI in window form

Comment: Indeed, that was my bad. Thank you Klaycon!

Comment: Yes, but I still have one point left, which is rounding the answer for BMI Result, as you can see in 'after running this code' picture, you can see all the numbers after decimal

Comment: @Oso I picked a poor dupe target as it's not your exact question, but the method to round is exactly the same.. simply use `Math.Round(num,decimalPlaces)`

Comment: Also, if you use `else if`, you don't have to re-test previous conditions

Comment: Yes my bad, I am thinking of removing this question because it shouldnt have been here to begin with. And thank you Rufus, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

> *"I still fail to understand the difference between* `||` *and* `&&`*"*

The differences are described in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-), but basically:

- The result of an `&&` operation will be `true` if *both* sides of the operator evaluate to `true`.
- The result of an `||` operation will be `true` if *either* side of the operator evaluates to `true`.

In your case, the use of `&&` is correct, but the problem is the conditions being tested. To test if the value is greater than or equal to `18.5` AND is less than `25`, the condition should be:

```
if (BMI >= 18.5 && BMI < 25.0)
```

---

With that said, we can simplify the conditions a little by using `else if`, which builds upon the original `if` condition (i.e. the `else if` is only evaluated if the previous `if` failed). This means we don't have to test if `BMI >= 18.5` if we use an `else if`, because if we get there it means the previous `if` condition failed, and that condition was testing if `BMI < 18.5`.

For example, your logic could be simplified to:

```
if (BMI < 18.5) 
{
    lbdescription.Text = "BMI Description: Your weight is extremely low";
    return;
}
else if (BMI < 25.0) // if we get here, we know that BMI is >= 18.5
{
    lbdescription.Text = "BMI Description: Your weight is in line with average";
}
else if (BMI < 30.0) // if we get here, we know that BMI is >= 25.0
{
    lbdescription.Text = "BMI Description: Your weight is over";
}
else // if we get here, we know BMI is >= 30.0 
{
    lbdescription.Text = "BMI Description: Your weight is excess";
}
```

---

> *"Also, how do I round BMI result into the nearest 10?"*

If you meant the nearest 10th (i.e. first decimal place), you can use the `Math.Round()` method, and pass it the number of decimal places you want to round a number to. For example:

```
BMI = Math.Round(BMI, 1); // Will round a number like 18.23 to 18.2 (will round down on .5)
```

If you mean you want to round to the nearest tens place, then you could divide by 10, round the number, and then multiply by ten:

```
BMI = Math.Round(BMI / 10) * 10; // Will round to nearest tens (126 will become 130)
```